# Azure SDK API and JAVA usage - Issue Listing all Containers and BLOBS inside a storage account

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

Issues while using **client.listContainers()** and **container.listBlobs()** functions and getting below JAVA exception. Tried to access them individually with reference methods and it works fine. Not sure why this is happening as there are no access restrictions i.e public access and getting the client reference without any issues of Connection String.

---

**Exception:**

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
at com.company.test.core.handler.AzureHeirarchyGenerator.getAzureFileList(AzureHeirarchyGenerator.java:69)
at com.company.test.core.handler.AzureHeirarchyGenerator.main(AzureHeirarchyGenerator.java:18)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: An unknown failure occurred : Connection refused: connect
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:66)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:209)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)
... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:115)
... 3 more
```

---

**Code Snippet JAVA:**

```
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(azureConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    // List all containers of a storage account
    Iterable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = client.listContainers();
    for (CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer : containers) {
        Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = cloudBlobContainer.lisBlobs();
        System.out.println("Code to fetch blobs inside container");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Lee, Issue was with the POM and the Azure SDK version which was added as dependency. With proper references code works without issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and it worked fine in my environment as below:

[image]

Here is my full code for your reference:

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.ListBlobItem;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CloudStorageAccount account;
    try {
        account = CloudStorageAccount.parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=leeliublob;AccountKey=O7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/x/e9l9FhLqayXcbz1R+E0mIcJ5Wjkly1DsQPYY5dF2JrAVHtBozbJo29ZrrGJA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        Iterable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = client.listContainers();
        for (CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer : containers) {
            Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = cloudBlobContainer.listBlobs();
            System.out.println("BlobContainer : "+ cloudBlobContainer.getName());
            System.out.println("   blobs inside container '"+cloudBlobContainer.getName()+"' are: ");
            int x=1;
            for (ListBlobItem blobItem : cloudBlobContainer.listBlobs()) {
                String blobName = blobItem.getUri().toString();
                System.out.println("         Number "+x+": url="+ blobItem.getUri().toString());
            x++;
            }

        }
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }

}
```

I guess there may be two reasons which cause your errors:

1. Please ensure that the connection string is correct.
2. Please ensure to use the latest Java SDK 
   and the SDK of Java which i used from : [azure-storage-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java)

Comment: I have question for clarification: For blobItem is a Image. If i want to save the blobItem to BufferedImage means how i get the content of blobItem